# PHP using false to break out of if/else shorthand

Tags: php

Playing around with PHP if/else shorthand and wondering if this is acceptable:

```
$pages = get_children(array(
    'post_parent'   =>  49,
    'post_type'     => 'page',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
));

$html = '';
$first = true;
$first_id = null;

foreach ($pages as $page) :
    $html .= '<li class=""><a href="" class="js-load-sub-nav' . ( $first ? " is-active" : "" ) . '" data-id="' . $page->ID . '" data-action="af_contact_nav_child_pages">' . $page->post_title . '</a></li>';
    ( $first ? $first_id = $page->ID : false );
    $first = false;
endforeach;
```

Snippet in question:

```
( $first ? $first_id = $page->ID : false );
```

Seems to work fine??

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did...seems to work fine, but is it an ugly technique? Is there a better method?

Comment: Seems pointless. Why not just do an if($first) ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. This is by personal taste; of course. When I found out about ternary operators, thought it was the best thing since sliced bread ;-)

Comment: @Kolby I'm just playing around with shorthand

Comment: I think a better solution will be if($first) $first_id = $page->ID; Still one line and doesn't have any unnecessary code.

Comment: @Kolby you're right :) but nice to know this at least works. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique is well known - called the ternary operator. I don't think it is ugly :)

You can even omit the `false` if you switch the logic:

```
!$first ?: $first_id = $page->ID;
```

Note that only the part behind the `?` can be kept empty.

Comment: @SamHolguin Thanks! only the first part can be kept empty... Didn't knew that (and wondering why)...